# Datetime parsing for Ical files

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, icalendar

I am taking in a timezone (req.body.TIMEZONE), and a datetime start - end from a form.  I am trying to display the time back and make an Ical file with it however whenever I do new Date(string) I get the time 7 hours ahead?  I am trying to use moment?  How can I display the local time to the user in the ical file??

```
        var cal = ical();
            cal.domain('gmail.com');


            var dateFormat = 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm+00:00';
            console.log(req.body.START_TIME); //2016-10-03 10:40 am

            var startTime = moment(req.body.START_TIME);
            var localDateStart = startTime.local();
            console.log(localDateStart.format(dateFormat));  // 2016-03-10 10:40+00:00
            console.log(new Date(localDateStart.format(dateFormat))); // invalid... wants the same time


            var endTime = moment(req.body.END_TIME);
            var localDateEnd = endTime.local();
            console.log(localDateEnd.format(dateFormat)); 

            var event = cal.createEvent({

                start: new Date(localDateStart.format(dateFormat)),
                end: new Date(localDateEnd.format(dateFormat)),
                summary: req.body.TITLE,
                location: req.body.LOCATION,
                description: req.body.DESCRIPTION,
                organizer: req.body.HOSTED + " <" + req.body.EMAIL + ">",
                url: req.body.URL
            });
```

Comment: Given the format indicated, the result of `new Date(req.body.START_TIME)` is implementation dependent. Why use a library to parse the string sometimes but not others?

Comment: @RobG I am always using moment, as I am parsing it an reassigning the same variable.  However the real time comes back but when I display it its shown in GMT where i want PST.

Comment: You aren't "always using moment", e.g. in `new Date(localDateStart.format(dateFormat))` and assuming *localDateStart* is a moment object, you're using moment to generate a string, then letting *Date* parse it, which is a very bad idea. Instead use `localDateStart.clone()`, see [*moment clone*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [get the JavaScript Date instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for start and end times.  Once you have that, timezone offsets are applied from there.  The Date can be instantiated from string concatenation.

[This guys says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139132/how-to-make-javascript-date-prototype-tostring-always-display-local-time-zone):

> As a rule: ALWAYS store and process dates as UTC time until you're
>   going to display them to the users. If you're reading local times from
>   the user, you need to convert them to UTC time at the earliest
>   possible moment and keep them as that until you display them again.

[Here's an online timestamper I created](https://rack.pub/timestamp) that might shed light.

[image]